# Is this form of proof circular reasoning?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

This is a general question about trivial proofs. Recently in a textbook I was reading there was simple exercise in the form:

> Prove that $\frac{1}{1 - \sqrt2} = -(1 + \sqrt2)$

I can prove this simply by multiplying like this:
$\frac{1 * (1 + \sqrt2)}{(1 - \sqrt2) * (1 + \sqrt2)} = \frac{1 + \sqrt2}{-1} = -(1 + \sqrt2)$

However, my question is this, can I also prove questions like this by manipulating *both* sides of the supposed equality, or does that in some way assume what I'm trying to prove? I'll give an example of what I mean with the above exercise.

So instead of just multiplying the numerator and denominator to reach my answer, I multiply *both sides* of the equation(?) by $1 -\sqrt2$ so that:

$\frac{1}{1 - \sqrt2} * (1 - \sqrt2) = -(1 + \sqrt2) * (1 - \sqrt2) = $

$1 = -(1 - 2) = -(-1) = 1$

I.e. we've arrived at a truth (that 1 = 1) from our supposed truth. Would this also constitute a proof? I feel like it doesn't, but I can't quite explain why. It seems circular, but maybe it's not.

If anyone could clarify that would be great!

Comment: You are right. This is fallacious.

Comment: It's not circular.  It is simply invalid.  Proving that if you do the same thing to two things and get the same result doesn't mean they are the same. Consider $1 = 5\implies 1-3 = 5-3 \implies (1-3)^2 = (5-3)^2 \implies 4= 4$ TA-DA $1=5$.  That's simply not a proof.

Comment: @fleablood It looks quite valid to me.  The valid form of argument being: start with $A \stackrel{?}{=} B$,  i.e. an equality we'd like to verify, and transform that (not yet verified) equality into equivalent (not yet verified) equalities via reversible steps.  If we reach, via this sequence of equivalences, a statement that is true, as the OP did, then the original equality must be true, Q.E.D.  Your "counterexample" isn't an example of this form, because it uses a non-reversible step; that is, $1-3=5-3$ is *not* equivalent to $(1-3)^2=(5-3)^2$. OP's proof used no such non-reversible steps.

Comment: But the OP *NEVER* considered whether the steps were reversable.  S/he only showed them it be implications in precisely the *wrong* direction.   The entire proof hinges on the assumption that if $A\implies B$ and $B$ is true, then $A$ is true.  And that is simply wrong.  It doesn't matter that it could be (but utterly was *not* shown) that $B\implies A$ if that is *never* shown, used or stated.

Comment: @fleablood Well, if someone you regarded as competent presented a proof such as OP's to you, I'm guessing you'd make the good-faith assumption that the form of argument ey are using using is the valid one, and not the invalid one... right? Agreed OP probably didn't consider whether the steps were reversible (I'm sure ey didn't given that ey said it didn't seem valid); and I think that is the crux of the most useful answer to this question: *yes*, that "backwards" proof is quite valid, as is that general form of argument, *if* you are careful to make sure each step is an equivalence.

Comment: Also of note, I have seen this "backwards" form of proof dismissed as "your scratch notes, not something you'd hand in to your professor unless ey asked you to show all your work".   I disagree with this, for two reasons: (1) the "backwards" reasoning is in fact the reasoning one typically uses when *solving* such a problem and exploring the space; rewriting it forwards, although it may look superficially cleaner, also makes it opaque so the reader is less motivated to follow. (2) the backwards proof gives the reader practice in the line of reasoning that can be used to solve similar problems.

Comment: "if someone you regarded as competent presented a proof such as OP's to you,"  Someone I regarded as competent wouldn't ask me for my approval.  And even then I'd expect a few scribbles and hedge words such as "it is sufficient to" or the "result *will* follow from".  However I will ride hard on a novice because they *are* a novice and recognizing conditional implication is such a VERY important concept and it is so *easy* and ***common*** to get it wrong that I think riding anyone who doesn't specifically point it out is entirely justified.

Comment: @fleablood Agreed, calling out clearly that this is what you're doing is important, and I wouldn't call them hedge words, either.  "it is sufficient to" and "result will follow from" are precisely the phrases that need to be included in order to make such a proof clear.  *That* is what needs to be pointed out to the novice, I think.  Before ey evolve into a hardened professional who won't listen to you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, but it's not circular reasoning. It's another type of fallacious argument called affirming the consequent. Just because something implies a true statement doesn't mean it is true. For instance, the statement "for all $a$ and $b,$ $a+b = a\cdot b$" implies the true statement $2+2=2\cdot 2,$ but it's obviously false.

However, any statement that implies a false statement must be false, so if you'd derived $1=0$ you'd be justified in concluding the original equation was false.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in general is not valid. Trivially, we could multiply both sides by $0$ and get $0=0$ no matter what.  However, if $f$ is any function that is bijective, that is it has an inverse $f^{-1}$ such that $f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$ and $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$, then we generally have $x = y \iff f(x) = f(y)$.  The domain of $f$ matters for whether $f$ is a bijection or not. $f(x) = x^2$ is a bijection if we restrict the domain to either numbers $\geq 0$ or numbers $\leq 0$. So it's valid to say $-1 = -2/2$ because $(-1)^2 = (-2/2)^2$, but it's not valid to say $-1 = 1$ because $(-1)^2 = 1^2$ as the latter requires using $f(x)=x^2$ at both positive and negative numbers. Similarly, for real numbers $f(x)=x^3$ is bijective, but it isn't for complex numbers.  Multiplying both sides by an invertible value or adding a value are always bijective operations. So the logical structure of a proof that "does the same thing to both sides" is $$a = b \impliedby f(a) = f(b) \impliedby g(f(a)) = g(f(b)) \impliedby h(g(f(a))) = h(g(f(b)))$$ where $f$, $g$, and $h$ are bijections, and $h(g(f(a)))=h(g(f(b)))$ is obviously true, e.g. $1=1$. Each bijection corresponds to one "step" of the proof.

So your second proof is valid because $f(x)=(1-\sqrt{2})x$ is a bijection.